# Jquery button background change

Tags: jquery

i have some jquery code that changes my button when clicked to show another button; (they are background button images)

but i cant get it to show the background image. i can change its colour but dont know how to add bg image.

change someone explain where i need to change the code

```
$('.chartme-btn-main').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('att') == 0){
          $(this).css('background', '');
        $(this).attr('att',1);
    } else {
          $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
        $(this).attr('att',0);
    }
  });
```

Any help would be great!!!!

Comment: Where is the code that changes the image?

Comment: Don't use custom attributes, use rather `data-*` attribute instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a sprite image and just change the `background-position`,
**the good thing about this approach is that there's no wait for the request to load a new image**

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eVUGaSO/2/edit)**

CSS:

```
.chartme-btn-main{
  background:url('images/buttonSprite.jpg');
}

.chartme-btn-main.active{
  background-position: 0px -210px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.chartme-btn-main').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.chartme-btn-main').click(function() {
    $(this)
        .css('background', $(this).data('att') == 0 
            ? 'none' 
            : 'yellow url(yourimagepath)')
        .data('att', $(this).data('att') == 0 
            ? 1 
            : 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/wvLYd

```
var imgUrl = "http://silverspaceship.com/static/shot_1.png";
$(this).css('background', 'url('+imgUrl+')');
```

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/wvLYd/2/

better solution: "no wait for the request to load a new image" by @Paul O'Brien

Comment: var imgUrl = "images/chart-button-sprite.png 0 -98px no-repeat";
$('.chartme-btn-main').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('att') == 0){
        $(this).css('background', '');
        $(this).attr('att',1);
    } else {
        $(this).css('background', 'url('+imgUrl+')');
        $(this).attr('att',0);
    }
});

Comment: of course ... rafaelcastrocouto from gmail.com (im following you on twitter)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var imgUrl = "http://silverspaceship.com/static/shot_1.png";
$(this).css('background', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');
```